# Does C# Compiler calculate math on constants?

Tags: c#, performance, constants, compiler-optimization

Given the following code:

```
const int constA = 10;
const int constB = 10;

function GetX(int input) {
    int x = constA * constB * input;
    ...
    return x;
}
```

Will the .Net compiler 'replace' the expression and put 1000 so the calculation won't be repeated over and over?

In what siutation will the code run fastest:

1. ```
   int x = constA * constB * input;
   ```
2. ```
   int x = 10 * 10 * input;
   ```
3. ```
   int x = 100 * input;
   ```

I guess option 3 will be the faster then 2 but sometimes not the most readable option. Does the compiler recognize patterns like this and optimize it accordingly?

Comment: You mean put '100' instead of '1000' :) Could you not check this with for example ILSpy?

Comment: At the end of the day you still have to multiply by a variable `input`, which will be the bottleneck. So why bother?

Comment: Given question was simplified to show the problem real fast. I could of course give you the complete inheritance of classes etc etc... but I have chosen not to.

Comment: Off topic, if you have multiple calls to the `GetX` method, you could improve it's performance by getting rid of the `x` variable and use `return constA * constB * input;` instead of `return x;`.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici - that's a fairly bald assertion, given we don't know what `...` does (including, any accesses to `x`), and that we don't know what the JIT would necessarily do if those *were* the only parts of the `GetX` function. Asserting that eliminating a local variable would (without any qualification) improve performance is unwarranted.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[C# Constant Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691319%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> Whenever an expression is of one of the types listed above and contains only the constructs listed above, the expression is evaluated at compile-time. This is true even if the expression is a sub-expression of a larger expression that contains non-constant constructs.

(and much more to read, if you want to) The "above" referred to is a bulleted list, including:

> - References to const members of class and struct types.

and,

> - The predefined +, –, *, /, %, <<, >>, &, |, ^, &&, ||, ==, !=, <, >, <=, and >= binary operators, provided each operand is of a type listed above.

So, to directly answer your question, yes, the compiler will perform the calculation at compile time.

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constants `Constants are immutable values which are known at compile time and do not change for the life of the program.`

Answer (score 11):

I tried this in LINQPad:

```
const int constA = 2;
const int constB = 50;

void Main()
{

    Console.WriteLine(GetX(12));
}

int GetX(int input) 
{
    int x = constA * constB * input;

    return x;
}
```

The IL is :

[image]

The hex 64 value (100 in decimal) is the result of the multiplication of the constants. The mul operation is the multiplication by `input`.

So it sounds like the operations applied to the constants are optimized by the compiler.

Comment: Oops, typo. Fixed. Thanks !