# Precomputation of constants (Is there a performance difference?)

Tags: c#

Is the compiler 'smart enough' to precompute this, or will it have a performance impact?

```
const float num = 0.8660254f; // Sqrt(3) / 2

while(true)
{
  float h = num * GetSomeNumber();
}
```

vs

```
while(true)
{
   float h = (Sqrt(3) / 2 ) * GetSomeNumber();
}
```

vs

```
const float num = 1.7320508f; // Sqrt(3)

while(true)
{
  float h = (num / 2) * GetSomeNumber();
}
```

And is there any reason to (not) precompute?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does C# Compiler calculate math on constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752559/does-c-sharp-compiler-calculate-math-on-constants)

Comment: Sharplab is great for this https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYZQAs6AsgBQCU+hxTAxgPYB2AzgC7oBmAG1YBDXuwCuAW3QBedAAYAdAA4AbKvkwArGT4BudAHpD6AMoBHAE7dqqeiZiMmRNl16CRYqTFno4igHZUGHkteWV9IxMLa1taZASkIg9RdAALXwlpACp0AHEAU25TVkkCgDkpACMCyzo9ZBTeAEtfaibaakpRNMUYmzsjdB96XMLi0orq2vqnZ34hVIArNqyfB1H8opKyyskautoGpDmAXzmmrYnd6cO5giT5zAD0AP0zueRToA

Comment: The "duplicate" isn't a duplicate. `Math.Sqrt(3)` is NOT a constant, at least as far as C# is concerned. But the correct answer is: [If you want to know which horse is faster then race your horses.](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the compiler does not do any computation. Computation or execution of the code is a runtime thing. The compiler is smart enough to do multiple adjustments to the code for performance, but it does not have any idea about what method you are calling at runtime. So it won't know how your method `Sqrt` behaves at runtime. And hence, it will not be able to perform calculations beforehand during compilation.